# Need to send &search=1 command with submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have setup a search page and now i need to make the button submit it to search.php

```
    <form name="myform" action="search.php">
    Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
    document.myform.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

I have this script which enters the information onto the next search window but does not submit it. This sends a command query="Input" but i need it to send a command saying query="input" &search=1
How can i achieve that? thank you for any help! :)

Comment: On the bright side, i will never ask this question again :)

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden form field: `<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1" />`.

```
<form name="myform" action="search.php">
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1" />
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: change S to lowercase.

Comment: OP's question specifies upper case

Comment: Not at the title.. but right, that's not your fault.

Comment: Ah, I see that. I think they're just confused.

Comment: I think that's way too minor. The OP will figure it out when using the answer

Comment: The question title was correct, my question should have been with lower case "search" , still new to all this, did not pay enough attention to lower/upper cases, noted , wont happen again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any component(like textbox) for "Search" then you can take the value from request parameter in your search.php file, if you dont have any such take a hidden text field add the "search" and give the value "1" , the hidden parameters can be accessed once you submit the form or you can use ajax.